# Select dates one cell at a time

Tags: excel

I have a small macro that performs an action and should then put the contents of the next A cell into B25. The macro works well until I close the sheet. When I reopen the sheet B25 shows #NAME? error and =@A0 in cell. Running the macro a second time starts from =A1 again.

nd is a variable for Next Date

Sub Reset_values()

```
Static nd As Integer
Range("E5:K5").ClearContents
Range("B25").Select
ActiveCell = "=A" & nd
nd = nd + 1
Range("E5").Select
```

End Sub

In simple terms I need a way to save the last value of nd to be saved so that the sheet resumes with B25 having the value of A&nd. Running the macro hundreds + times until it reaches the right date is not what I intended. If anyone can explain what I am doing wrong I would be so grateful.

Thank you for looking at my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't let `nd` be zero ! :

```
Sub Reset_values()

    Static nd As Long

    If nd = 0 Then nd = 1
    Range("E5:K5").ClearContents
    Range("B25").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=A" & nd
    nd = nd + 1
    Range("E5").Select
End Sub
```